# No service for type 'MyType' has been registered

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a generic repository architecture that looks like this:

**Repository**

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T: class
{
    IList<T> Get(Func<T, bool> where);
}

public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T: class
{
    private readonly DbSet<T> _entity;

    protected Repository(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _entity = dbContext.Set<T>();
    }

    public IList<T> Get(Func<T, bool> where)
    {
        return _entity.Where(where).ToList();
    }
}
```

Then concrete implementations are created like this:

**UserRepository**

```
public class UserRepository : Repository<ApplicationUser>
{
    public UserRepository(ApplicationDbContext dbContext) : base(dbContext) {}

    // Can add any other methods I want that aren't included in IRepository
}
```

I'll likely have quite a few services, so rather than having each one passed into the controller individually, I thought I'd try passing in a single factory that can produce repositories for me.

**RepositoryFactory**

```
public interface IRepositoryFactory
{
    T GetRepository<T>() where T : class;
}

public class RepositoryFactory : IRepositoryFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _provider;

    public RepositoryFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _provider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public T GetRepository<T>() where T : class
    {
        return _provider.GetRequiredService<T>(); // ERROR: No service for type 'UserRepository' has been registered
    }
}
```

Now, in setting up dependency injection, I registered the services like this:

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // [...]

    services.AddScoped<IRepository<ApplicationUser>, UserRepository>();
    services.AddScoped<IRepositoryFactory, RepositoryFactory>();

    // [...]
}
```

This is all used in the controller like this:

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserRepository _userRepository;

    public HomeController(IRepositoryFactory repositoryFactory)
    {
        _userRepository = repositoryFactory.GetRepository<UserRepository>(); // ERROR: No service for type 'UserRepository' has been registered
    }

    // [...]
}
```

When I call `_provider.GetRequiredService<T>()` in the `repositoryFactory.GetRepository<UserRepository>()` method, I get the error in the comment above.

The `RepositoryFactory` is coming through just fine, but the `UserRepository` isn't getting registered. What am I missing? I've tried calling the `GetRepository` method outside of the constructor, and I've tried change `AddScoped` to the other `Add` variants (Transient and Singleton), but to no avail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are taking dependency on `UserRepository`, which is implementation and not interface, that's not good (given that you actually have that interface registered in container). Instead you need to take dependency on interface: `IRepository<ApplicationUser>`. So change your factory interface:

```
public interface IRepositoryFactory
{
    IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>() where T : class;
}
```

Implementation:

```
public IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>() where T : class
{
    return _provider.GetRequiredService<IRepository<T>>(); // ERROR: No service for type 'UserRepository' has been registered
}
```

And controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRepository<ApplicationUser> _userRepository;

    public HomeController(IRepositoryFactory repositoryFactory)
    {
        _userRepository = repositoryFactory.GetRepository<ApplicationUser>(); // ERROR: No service for type 'UserRepository' has been registered
    }

    // [...]
}
```

Now it doesn't work, because you registered `IRepository<ApplicationUser>` in container (with implementation being `UserRepository`), but `UserRepository` which you are trying to resolve is not registered (and as said above - you should not resolve it anyway).

Comment: We were both typing our answers at the same time, but I think we're both saying essentially the same thing. This was the solution.

Comment: This is the solution for my problem, where in a `.cshtml` view, I did `@inject MyService` implementation when I should have used `@inject IMyService` interface.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like my problem had to do with my understanding of `AddScoped`. Looking at the docs, the two type parameters in `AddScoped` are `TService` and `TImplementation`. So in my Startup class above, the **SERVICE** I'm registering is `IRepository<ApplicationUser>`, not `ApplicationRepository`. The **IMPLEMENTATION** I'm registering is `ApplicationRepository`.

To fix this, I changed my `Startup` class to say that `UserRepository` is the service being registered.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // [...]

    // OLD: services.AddScoped<IRepository<ApplicationUser>, UserRepository>();
    services.AddScoped<UserRepository>();
    services.AddScoped<IRepositoryFactory, RepositoryFactory>();

    // [...]
}
```

But this approach relies on an implementation rather than an abstraction (interface), so I took it a step further and introduced an interface for the `UserRepository` class and registered that in `Startup`.

**UserRepository**

```
public interface IUserRepository : IRepository<ApplicationUser>
{
    void DoTheThing();
}

public class UserRepository : Repository<ApplicationUser>, IUserRepository
{
    public UserRepository(ApplicationDbContext dbContext) : base(dbContext) {}

    public void DoTheThing()
    {

    }
}
```

**Startup**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // [...]

    services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
    services.AddScoped<IRepositoryFactory, RepositoryFactory>();

    // [...]
}
```