# Injecting DbContext and Repository into class library service constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, design-patterns, dependency-injection, blazor

I'm getting an error using DI in a service located in a different class library to my main blazor application.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Services.SomeService' has been registered.
```

This is what the Service looks like currently (it resides in it's own class library):

```
public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
    
    private IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> DbContextFactory { get; set; }
    private IGPSFixRepository GpsFixRepository { get; set; } = default!;
    
    public SomeService(IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> contextSQLDb, IGPSFixRepository gpsFixRepository)
    {
        DbContextFactory = contextSQLDb;
        this.GpsFixRepository = gpsFixRepository;
    }
    
}
```

The constructor for the GPSFixRepository requires a context factory:

```
public GPSFixRepository(IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> contextSQLDb)
```

I have declared the services in the client Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionStringIdentity));
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISomeService, SomeService>();
```

I'm assuming that the DI is not able to create an instance of the IGPSFixRepository since it requires the context factory in it's constructor.

How do I inform the DI such that it creates a context factory when creating the IGPSFixRepository?

Comment: You are assuming wrong. The exception message is telling you what's incorrect. The DI is trying to resolve dependency of `SomeService`, but it fails since there is none registered. Look again at your code registering `SomeService` and analyze it closely. Is it really exposing your `SomeService` for use within the DI? Or maybe it's there, but it's cloaked under something?

Comment: Your DI needs to call the registered interface, `ISomeService`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No service for type 'MyType' has been registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307739/no-service-for-type-mytype-has-been-registered)

Answer (score 1):

When you call:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISomeService, SomeService>();
```

This only exposes `ISomeService` through DI. You will need to *also* call:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<SomeService>();
```

In order for it to be resolved correctly.

Comment: Well, the person should probably just inject ISomeService and use that.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 Yes, but as specified in the original question, it is an external class library that is causing the exception, so the only solution is to register the concrete class directly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks **jhmckimm** and **Bennyboy1973**, you did help me solve this issue.

The issue was I was newing up a *ServiceCollection* to use Dependency Injection within a static class. I hadn't done the:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISomeService>();
```

in this new *ServiceCollection*, although I had done it in **Program.cs**

Obviously the declaration in **Program.cs** has no impact on the new *ServiceCollection*, so I needed to add it to my static method.

So this is what I did within my static method:

```
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
        services.AddScoped<ISomeService, SomeService>();
        services.AddScoped<IGPSFixRepository, GPSFixRepository>();
```

That did it - makes total sense, not sure why I did not grok this.

For those interested in why I'm doing this in a static method, it is because I'm using a Blazor JSInvokable method called from Javascript.